# Onclick in onclick function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a basic problem with showing modal. Everything is working ok, but only for second click. I am sure, I have some mistake in js code. Can you help me please?

HTML code:

```
    <div class="flex flex-col lg:flex-row justify-center px-3 lg:px-0">
     <div class="pb-3 lg:pb-0 lg:p-5 cursor-pointer">
      <img onclick="showImage('planek1')" id="planek1" src="assets/imgs/planek1.jpg" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="cursor-pointer lg:p-5">
      <img onclick="showImage('planek2')" id="planek2" src="assets/imgs/planek2.jpg" alt="">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
     <span class="close">&times;</span>
     <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
     <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>
```

Javascript code:

```
    function showImage(id) {
     const modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
     const img = document.getElementById(id);
     const modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
     img.onclick = function () {
      modal.style.display = "block";
      modalImg.src = this.src;
    };
    const span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    span.onclick = function () {
     modal.style.display = "none";
    };
   }
```

Comment: Your event listener registers another event listener, why is that?

Comment: I guess there is a problem - i wanted to use only one function for two different pics, because they are doing same thing

Comment: Good idea, the problem is you don't want to execute that function on the click event, please take a look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing `onclick="showImage('planek2')"`, give a `class="triggers-modal"` to your elements, and write this JavaScript:

```
const modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
const span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
span.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "none";
};

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('triggers-modal')).forEach(element => {
        element.onclick = function () {
            modal.style.display = "block";
            modalImg.src = this.src;
        };
    });
```

This code defines the modal behavior for every element that has the `triggers-modal` class name instead of the `onclick` event which is inappropriate.